# How to collapse a codename one accordion component programmatically?

Tags: codenameone

How to collapse a codename one accordion component programmatically?

In my App, I have an accordion that expands a body container with some radio buttons. I want to collapse (Close) the  body automatically when a radio button is selected.

Adding more details about the problem:

My intention is create a  component that has same behavior of a ComboBox, but using Accodion component as base class.
I wrote a minimal use case that reproduce the problem and you can get its source file here [MyApplication.java](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzc65Jiqgy3zOGw3Q3c5RnBkeWM/view?usp=sharing).
**This code implements Steve Hanna answer.I suppose. And it didn't work for me.**
 Running this code is simple.
Just create a CodeName One project and replace the MyApplication.java file generated by CodeName One Wizard and run the project (I use Netbeans IDE).
I put inside Radio Button action  the command to collapse the component as you can see at lines 271 til 280. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the radio button's action listener, check if it's not selected and then call [collapse(bodyContainer)](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/components/Accordion.html#collapse-com.codename1.ui.Component-) on the accordion.

EDIT: There was a bug in Accordion that caused collapse() to work incorrectly.  This has now been [fixed](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/2b9bef10abb79e1e73c8c77ac350908a40c11ee6), and will be available in the next plugin update.

See [this sample](https://gist.github.com/shannah/37a755ba2b949c2166fb23f143582fab) to see correct usage.

Note that after calling `collapse(component)`, you should call the Accordion's `animateLayout()` method so that the change is shown.

Comment: I did that. But it isn't work.
My command line is : IwAccrComboBox.this.collapse(cBody);

Comment: Post a more complete code example in your question and I might be able to point out problems.

Comment: I added more details on the body of the question.

Comment: Please, If possible, send me a short MyApplication.java with this feature working.

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect that I found a bug in Accordion that was causing this problem for you.

Comment: Thank you Steve for your Response. I'll wait for new version of CodenameOne's plugin. Do you know when it will be available?